# Get pairs of values satisfying condition based on mutual connection pandas

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graph-theory

Let's say I have following dataframe:

```
     index    A      B
     -----------------
      1      A1     B1
      2      A1     B2
      3      A1     B3
      4      A2     B1
```

How do I write a code that returns these pairs (Ax,By) that satisfy such condition that Ax is connected with more different Bs than By is connected with different As.

In this case it should return (A1, B1) because A1 is connected with 3 different Bs, but B1 is connected with 2 different As.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it should also return A1-B2 because A1 is connected to 3 Bs, while B2 is only connected to 1 A. Shouldn't it?

Comment: You're right, is then yatu's solution wrong?

Comment: not sure ... I had to read the question twice to understand that, in spite of the fact it's very clear. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do that (in a couple of steps, for clarity):

```
# Drop duplicates in case there are any
df = df.drop_duplicates() 

df["A_count"] = df.groupby("A")["B"].transform("count")
df["B_count"] = df.groupby("B")["A"].transform("count")
df[(df.A_count > df.B_count)]
```

The output is:

```
    A   B  A_count  B_count
0  A1  B1        3        2
1  A1  B2        3        1
2  A1  B3        3        1
```

Comment: Note that the problem is if `A1 - B1` appears multiple times (they are not linked to different *values*)

Comment: Are you referring to duplicate rows?

Comment: Yes, since op mentions `connected with more different...`, so that case would make it fail

Answer (score 5):

We could treat this as a graph problem, and check which of these *nodes* have a [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) higher than 1. Then just index on those rows where both values satisfy the condition:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='A', target='B')
keep = [node for node, deg in G.degree() if deg>1]
df[df[['A','B']].isin(keep).all(1)]

   index   A   B
0      1  A1  B1
```

Comment: After some tests I became to wonder if indeed this solution is correct. Doesn't this code just return the nodes that are mutually connected without actually checking the condition I provided?

Comment: No. It keeps those rows, in which both its values are connected with other values from the other column @Slajni

Comment: Yes, but id doesn't satisfy condition on the degree from one side being bigger than on the other. However it was easy modification after all.

Comment: Didn't reallize that was a condition, yes should be easy to adapt @slajni